# How do I install Drupal Console to my project with Composer?

Tags: 8, composer, console

I am running my Drupal 8 project under Acquia Dev Desktop 2 and just got Composer installed. How can I add the Drupal Console to my project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should follow the docs on the official Drupal Console repo on how to install it with Composer. Note that the global launcher is not recommended, it is recommended to add it to your project through Composer.

https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/blob/master/README.md

```
# Change directory to Drupal site
cd /path/to/drupal8.dev

# Download DrupalConsole
composer require drupal/console:~1.0 \
  --prefer-dist \
  --optimize-autoloader \
  --sort-packages
```

Note that the second command is all one command, not four. The `\` tells terminal the command is continuing to the next line.

Comment: > cd /path/to/drupal8.dev
"No such file or directory"
?
Composer require runs, but I can't get all commands:
"In order to list all of the available commands, you should run this against a drupal root directory.   "

Comment: It's wherever your project lives. That path is just an example.

Comment: just curious is Drupal Console always a dev, aka 'require-dev', dependency or just a regular 'require' dependency?

Comment: @armyofda12mnkeys I add it as `require-dev` as I don't want to use it on production.

Answer (score 0):

In your drupal root folder just run `composer require drupal/console`, and after that add path_to_your_drupal_installtion\vendor\bin to your system PATH environment variables, and restart your cli. (Windows   )...

Answer (score 0):

you can install `drupal console` using `composer`

open the command line on windows then go to :

```
cd /path/to/drupal8.dev
```

now you can install `drupal console` :

```
composer require drupal/console:~1.0 --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
```

after that you installed `drupal console` you can use it from drupal root directory where composer.json exist as follow:

```
vendor/bin/drupal <the_command>
```

you should replace `<the_command>` with one of the `drupal console` commands. you can see complete list of the commands here: [drupal console commands](https://drupalconsole.com/docs/en/commands/)